# ValueError: strides should be of length 1, 1 or 3 but was 2

Tags: image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, keras-layer

train input shape :  (13974, 100, 6, 5)

train output shape :   (13974, 1,1)

test input shape :   (3494, 100, 6, 5)

test output shape :   (3494, 1, 1)

I am developing the following model. of 2D CNN LSTM.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(1, (1,1), activation='relu', 
input_shape=(6,5,1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(6, 5))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(units=300, return_sequences= False, input_shape=(100,1)))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

when I try to fit as follow

```
model.fit(train_input,train_output,epochs=50,batch_size=60)
```

it gives me a error.

> ValueError: strides should be of length 1, 1 or 3 but was 2

please correct my model. I am converting the 6,5 image to a single unit and predict the 101th time stamp from 100 time stamps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear, but I believe you have sequence of 100 images of size 6 x 5. It is better to incorporate `Conv3D` in your usecase, and also there is no necessary to have `TimeDistributed` everywhere. This is just an illustration for your usecase, you may have to add more layers of `Conv` and `MaxPool` and experiment with other hyper-parameters to get good fit.

```
# Add the channel dimension in input
train_input = np.expand_dims(train_input, -1)
# Remove the extra dimension in output
train_output = np.reshape(train_output, (-1, 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(1, (1,1,1), activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 6,5, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(6, 5, 1)))
model.add(Reshape((16, 5)))
model.add(LSTM(units=300, return_sequences= False))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I am making a model to predict from 100 timestamps of a image of 6*5 and output to 6*1 I changed the last dense as Dense(6) whether the lstm gets the inputs of 100 time stamps and predict the output.